# lookup function appears to malfunction when looking up calculated cells

Tags: excel, lookup

i'm solving some problem in the field of simulation using excel sheet ...
in my problem i have some values , each value is assigned a range of numbers depending on some probability
a random number is generated , and a value is selected depending on the random number range.

e.g. if X lies between 1 to 20 then the value is A
if X between 21 to 40 then the value is B ...etc

i used lookup function to do that , , ,

the problem is that lookup seems to return incorrect results because range cells are calculated and not value cells
but when i clear formulas and put raw values instead, lookup goes fine
please take a look at the sheet, it contains some more description
the link will open excel app, click file >> Save as

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AACA397344081574!1131&authkey=!AL3dOAFRbmZfqMA&ithint=file%2c.xlsx

please check the file ... there is more description ,,,, i'm getting mad 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a rounding error - even though excel displays 87 (even with multiple decimal places), the calculated value used is probably something like 87.0000001, so use ROUND to fix, e.g. in I7 copied down

`=ROUND(J6+1,0)`

then your `LOOKUP` should work OK

see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) for causes

Comment: I ran this `=(J7-INT(J7))*9^99` and got `2.09700100346685E+80` as result instead of `0`. 57, 58, 86 and 87 are the only non-zero numbers there. Unless the others are even smaller than that...

Comment: Hi Jerry, perhaps I'm having a brain freeze but I'm not sure what you are saying - can you explain `"57, 58, 86 and 87 are the only non-zero numbers there. Unless the others are even smaller than that"` - thanks

Comment: Oh, I've just run the formula in my previous comment on all the numbers from OP's file and was just saying that the values are indeed something of the like of `87.0000 [...] 0001`. The decimal is just really small; almost unnoticeable even when you change the format to display many decimals. And it turns out that these 4 numbers have this small decimal; but not the rest, which explains why the other values did not give wrong results.